# How to block the xfce desktop right-click mouse menu

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, kiosk

I have a Linux Mint 14 machine and want to child-proof it.

My main concern right now is the menu that appears when I right-click on any empty desktop space.  I want to eliminate it from appearing.

Comment: This discussion might help you: http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=25805

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Xfce `4.10`, you may try the following:

In `Settings > Desktop > Menus` uncheck `Show applications on right click` and perhaps uncheck `Show window list on middle click`.

If in addition you go to `Settings > Desktop > Icons` and select `type:` `None` or `Minimized`, then this should pretty much disable all interaction with the desktop.